# height:auto? height:initial? or height:inherit?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, height

I have a small question: I have an element whose height is fixed to height: 50px; I put a media-queries when the device is lower than 600px, this same element has a height that adapts to the behavior of its children, which are in flex-wrap: wrap, What would you put this parent in: height: auto ? Height: initial? Or height: inherit? Why?

Comment: `height: auto`, to size with its content ... read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/height

Comment: Could you let me know what is missing in my answer, so I can adjust and you accept.

Answer (score 5):

In your case you could use either `height: auto` or `height: initial`, as the `height` property's default/initial value is `auto`.

`height: inherit` means it will inherit the value of its parents `height`, which might, or might not, be a value that will make it size to its content.

Read more here about the `height` property:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/height

Read more here about the `initial` value:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial_value